# How to extract state names from a string

Tags: r

This seem obvious but I can't figure it out. I have a vector of characters containing state names alongside random other words and would like to extract the state name.

```
df <- data.frame(string = c("The quick brown Arizona","jumps over the Alabama","dog Arkansas"))
```

I can create extract state names individually:

```
df$state[grepl("Alabama",df$string)] <- "Alabama"
```

but I can't figure out how to replicate that for all states without copying and pasting it 42 times. The closest I got was:

```
find.state <- function(x){
   df$state[grepl(x,df$string)] <- x
}
lapply(state.name, find.state)
```

but that just prints all the state names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a somewhat awkward regular expression.

```
df$state = sub(".*\\b(Arizona|Alabama|Arkansas)\\b.*", "\\1", df$string)
df
                   string    state
1 The quick brown Arizona  Arizona
2  jumps over the Alabama  Alabama
3            dog Arkansas Arkansas
```

Of course, you need to include the names of all the states, not just these three. So you might build that as a pattern first.

```
Pattern = paste0(paste0(".*\\b(", paste0(state.name, collapse="|")), ")\\b.*")
df$state = sub(Pattern, "\\1", df$string)
```

Comment: Thanks that works, especially together with the state.names vector mentioned by @Jared. However, I'm surprised there isn't a simple way to loop through the statenames with a `df$state[grepl(x,df$string)] <- x` function

Comment: @G5W This doesn't work if West Virginia is present in the data. It cannot isolate West Virginia and instead isolates Virginia. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

R comes with a variable holding the state names, `state.name`. Use `paste` to collapse it into one long character element, with `|` separating each state. This can be used as the search pattern for a regular expression.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$string, paste(state.name, collapse='|'))
```

Comment: yes I was using that in my failed lapply function above. This works in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

One option in the sample data provided by OP can be as:

```
gsub(".*\\s(\\w+)$","\\1",df$string)
#[1] "Arizona"  "Alabama"  "Arkansas"
```

**Regex:**

```
.*\s     - Look for anything followed by `space`
(\\w+)$  - Look for word character following last space till end. This will be state name.
```